# How can you create an admin interface that looks like a table?

Tags: python, django

I have a model where each object is conceptually a cell of a table - two ForeignKeys, `F` and `G` determine its position on the table (i.e., each tuple `(f,g)` is linked to one cell). That is, something like that:

```
class Cell(models.Model):
    f = models.ForeignKey(F)
    g = models.ForeignKey(G)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

When I create an admin page for that model using:

```
admin.site.register(Cell)
```

I get a page where each cell must be entered by linking to a `foo`, a `bar` and setting its `val` individually. For huge cells, that becomes cumbersome. It would be much more convenient to edit that information like so:

[image: desired table on admin]

Where `F_` and `G_` are objects of the `F` and `G` models, respectively.

Is it possible to get this interface on Django?

Comment: Why not write a custom view? You can add any templating you like.

Comment: What are `F` and `G`? Rather than `foo` and `bar` can you give some real world context to this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at django-tables2.  I haven't used it but read the docs whilst looking for other functionality and I think it might help you.

Also remembered this video which explains how you can make django work like a spreadsheet which may also be usful to you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jORuhbJq79M